# Knitr kable() output not displayed correctly when there are parenthesis in column title

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I have a linear model, for which I want to print a coefficient table in a knitr chunk inside a R markdown file. I produce a html file from this R markdown file.

```
> model <- lm(speed ~ dist, cars)
```

This coefficient table **is not** displayed correctly when I place it in a {r results='asis'} knitr chunk. The table is displayed as plain text in the html page.

```
> kable(xtable(model))


|            |  Estimate| Std. Error|  t value| Pr(>|t|)|
|:-----------|---------:|----------:|--------:|--------:|
|(Intercept) | 8.2839056|  0.8743845| 9.473985|        0|
|dist        | 0.1655676|  0.0174945| 9.463990|        0|
```

This coefficient table **is** displayed correctly when I place it in a {r results='asis'} knitr chunk. The table is displayed as an html table in the html page.

```
> kable(data.frame(xtable(model)))


|            |  Estimate| Std..Error|  t.value| Pr...t..|
|:-----------|---------:|----------:|--------:|--------:|
|(Intercept) | 8.2839056|  0.8743845| 9.473985|        0|
|dist        | 0.1655676|  0.0174945| 9.463990|        0|
```

Comment: what is your question? your post states that the table is and is not displayed correctly under the same circumstances. i assume a typo.

Comment: @Gary, I updated the question a little bit. My question is how to display the first table as an html table. I hope the example is clear enough to be reproduced?